# How to scale up texture without blurring it in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, textures, sprite-kit, image-scaling

If I have a low-res .png texture, how can I scale it up (to use it as an `SKSpriteNode`) without blurring the image? The same way Minecraft uses 16x16 pixel textures for blocks.
Obviously I could store a high-res version of the pixelated graphics, but that's a waste of storage space.
Is there any way to scale up textures in SpriteKit while preserving the pixelated look?

Comment: try `yourSKTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;`

Comment: Thanks, that works! I could only find an option like this for `CGImageRef` but that's a bit more complicated to use. `SKTexture` works just fine with that option set :)

Comment: @huocp add your comment as an answer, so that it may be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `yourSKTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;`